# How do I change properties using 'Object.prototype' method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Let's say:

```js
function MyObject() {
  this.val = true;
}

MyObject.prototype.toggleVal = function() {
  this.val = !this.val;
}

let x = new MyObject;
console.log(x.val); //true
x.toggleVal();
console.log(x.val);
//true /*this needs to be false now*/
```

In the above code, I want the 'toggleVal' method to change 'this.val'. But it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the desired result?

It is important that I change 'this.val' ONLY from this 'MyObject.prototype.toggleVal' method.

Comment: Have you ran your code? The value of `x.val` is `false` after running that code

Comment: It seems to work for me

Comment: I have converted your code to a snippet. If you run it you will see expected behaviour. The problem is somewhere else